# #unique on all properties of an event

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

In order for `HaltEvent` to be unique, all of `HaltEvent`s properties need to be taken into account.

So when creating a window, is there a shortcut / preferred way to say create a unique window with all the event’s properties?

Since there are a number of properties, trying to avoid to write the equivalent of:

```
context SingleDayContext
create window HaltWindow#unique(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) as HaltEvent
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I was experimenting with different options and tried what, in retrospect, should have been obvious upfront.

```
context SingleDayContext
create window HaltWindow#unique(*) as HaltEvent
;
```